# (PNG/ZIP) support not installed

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, zlib

I also encounter the problem : `*** support not installed.` when I use **PIL**.

> `---` PIL CORE support ok
>   `***` TKINTER support not installed
>   `***` JPEG support not installed
>   `***` ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support not installed
>   `---` FREETYPE2 support ok
>   `***` LITTLECMS support not installed

Many blogs say, if we append the path of where the `libz.so` exits in the `setup.py` (or make a link to `/usr/lib`), the problems will be solved.
However, neither I append the path (`libz.so` in my computer found in `/usr/lib64`),

```
add_directory(library_dirs,"/usr/lib64")
```

nor I make a link, even I copy it to `/usr/lib`, the problem still cannot be handled.

After copying to `/usr/lib`, both `libz.so` and `libjpeg.so` are in `/usr/lib`,

```
[chenzhongpu@chen lib]$ ls libjpeg.so libz.so 
libjpeg.so  libz.so
```

I have followed http://effbot.org/zone/pil-decoder-jpeg-not-available.htm, but it doesn't work.

One more thing, when I input

```
python setup.py build_ext -i
```

outout shows:

> `***` TKINTER support not available
>   `***` JPEG support not available
>   `---` ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
>   `---` FREETYPE2 support available
>   `***` LITTLECMS support not available

but when input,

```
python selftest.py
```

the output shows :

> ZLIB(PNG/ZIP) support no installed

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Really strange! After many tries, Now the install summary says                           --- JPEG support available 
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support available
--- FREETYPE2 support available                            But when I operate on PNG, it still told "IOError: decoder zip not available".why?

Comment: BTW, I can read from JPEG properly.

Comment: What's your OS/Python version? In my OSX I had similar problems with PIL and FreeType since the default download for PIL was not compiled with FreeType. I switched to installing freetype, python and pil from macports and my problem went away.